# advanced filter method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting above error. I have tried looking for answer, found few but none resolved my problem. usually solution was to activate sheet where filtering takes place. I'm coding in office 365 if it is of importance.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim kryteria, cel, zrodlo As Range
    Dim lRow, lRow2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sc1, sc2, sc3 As Range

    Worksheets("Dies").Range("B4:J100").Value = ""
    Sheets("Dies").ListObjects("Wyniki").Resize Range("$B$3:$J$3")

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If FDieSearch.Guma = "" Then
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 2) = "=*"
    Else
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 2) = "=" + FDieSearch.Guma
    End If

    If FDieSearch.Grubosc = "" Then
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 3) = "=*"
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 5) = "=*"
    Else
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 3) = ">=" + CStr(Int(FDieSearch.Grubosc) - 1)
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 5) = "<=" + CStr(Int(FDieSearch.Grubosc) + 1)
    End If

    If FDieSearch.Szerokosc = "" Then
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 4) = "=*"
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 6) = "=*"
    Else
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 4) = ">=" + CStr(Int(FDieSearch.Szerokosc) - 2)
        Sheets("Dies").Cells(2, 6) = "<=" + CStr(Int(FDieSearch.Szerokosc) + 2)
    End If

    Set kryteria = Sheets("Dies").Range("B1:F2")
    Set cel = Sheets("Dies").Range("B3:j100")
    Set zrodlo = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:I" & lRow)

    zrodlo.CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=kryteria, _
        CopyToRange:=cel, _
        Unique:=False

    lRow2 = Sheets("Dies").Cells(Sheets("Dies").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Dies").ListObjects("Wyniki").Resize Range("$B$3:$J$" & lRow2)

    Set ws = Sheets("Dies")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Wyniki")

    'Set sc1 = Range("Wyniki [STOCK]")
    Set sc2 = Range("Wyniki [Thickness]")
    Set sc3 = Range("Wyniki [Width]")

    With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=sc2, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=sc3, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

program is supposed to filter data in Data sheet based on values provided in userform FDieSearch, copy filtered data to Die sheet and sort results. But it keeps tripping on AdvanceFilter method.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One error is that when you are calculating the last non-blank cell in column A, you may not be referring to the same worksheet. When you use `Sheets("Data").Cells`, you're specifically qualifying the reference that the `Cells` are on `Sheets("Data")`. Then, when you want to count the `Rows`, there is no qualifying reference -- this means that `Rows.Count` is working with the currently active worksheet, which may not be `Sheets("Data")`. So your statement should be `lRow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Sheets("Data").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: Also, what are the values of `sc2` and `sc3` when you finally reach the `.SortFields` code?

Comment: @PeterT sc2 and sc3 should refer to column names on Dies worksheet in table called wyniki. i have found this code and wanted to try it out. basically table should be sorted firstly by thickness and secondly by width. but my code never reached that stage, so i dont know if it is correct. :/ Also, when running debug, last row is calculated correctly (520 in my case), but i'll try to include Your suggestion and see if it helps.Edit: No, sorry, still the same error.

Comment: Does `kryteria` have all the correct headings? You can remove the `currentregion` from your AF line, and try `Set cel = Sheets("Dies").Range("B3")` (though don't expect that to cause your error).

Comment: Yes, kryteria have correct headings. program worked fine for some time, then i've added sorting section, and it stopped working. Tried to trace back and return to original form, but without luck

Comment: Could this be the problem? https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2014/10/09/problem-with-advanced-filter-macro-and-table-slicer/

Comment: i have added two pictures with both sheets, hope it helps @SJR I have seen this link in my searches earlier. tried to activate cell once on Dies sheet, other time on Data sheet using sheets("nameofthesheet").cells(1,1).activate. still no joy

Answer (score 0):

I have found an error that helped me solve this problem. line:

```vb
Set zrodlo = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:I" & lRow)
```

is missing $s and after changing it to:

```vb
Set zrodlo = Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$I$" & lRow)
```

solved error issue.